# Need help on Linq with group by and distinct

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I am trying to perform a group by followed by a distinct to verify if a set of columns maps to only other column. For example, in the dataset below

```
Brand   Product      Location      Customer      Demand
 Box       A         Chicago       Chicago        10
 Box       B         Chicago       Milwaukee      20
 Cart      C         Madison       Milwaukee      10
 Cart      D         Chicago       Milwaukee      15
```

Product A, B, C are valid. But D is not valid since there exists a Product B with Chicago as Location & Milwaukee as Customer.
I am trying to build a LINQ query to get the exception record and having some trouble. I am very sure I have overcomplicated my query.

```
var vDuplicateSupplierLitho = from p in vRecords
                              group p by new
                              {
                                  Location = p["Location"].Cast<string>(),
                                  Customer = p["Customer"].Cast<string>()
                              } into grp
                              select new
                              {
                                  Location = grp.Key.Location,
                                  Customer = grp.Key.Customer,
                                  Products = from a in grp
                                             group a by new { Product = a["Product"].Cast<string>() } into apngrp
                                             where apngrp.Count() > 1 && apngrp.Select(a => a["Product"]).Distinct().Count() > 1
                                                  from NonUniqueRecord in apngrp
                                                  select new
                                                  {
                                                      Product = apngrp.key.Product,
                                                      Location = g.key.Location,
                                                      Customer = g.key.Customer
                                                      Demand = NonUniqueRecord["Demand"]
                                                  }
                                              };
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this Linq-To-DataSet? What does _"But D is not valid since there exists a Product A  with Chicago as Location & Milwaukee as Customer"_ mean? `Product A` has `Chicago` customer.

Comment: Hi, Yes, this is Linq to dataset. Sorry, there was a type. It should be Product B & D, they both have the same Location & Customer and it shouldn't be valid. So I need to return both the records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
new[] {
        new { Brand = "Box", Product = "A", Location = "Chicago", Customer = "Chicago", Demand = 10 },
        new { Brand = "Box", Product = "B", Location = "Chicago", Customer = "Milwaukee", Demand = 20 },
        new { Brand = "Cart", Product = "C", Location = "Madison", Customer = "Milwaukee", Demand = 10 },
        new { Brand = "Cart", Product = "D", Location = "Chicago", Customer = "Milwaukee", Demand = 15 },
        new { Brand = "Cart", Product = "C", Location = "Madison", Customer = "Milwaukee", Demand = 10 }
        }
    .GroupBy(o => new { o.Location, o.Customer })
    .Where(g => g.Select(o => o.Product).Distinct().Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(g => g)
```

... or, in query syntax ...

```
from record in new[] {
        new { Brand = "Box", Product = "A", Location = "Chicago", Customer = "Chicago", Demand = 10 },
        new { Brand = "Box", Product = "B", Location = "Chicago", Customer = "Milwaukee", Demand = 20 },
        new { Brand = "Cart", Product = "C", Location = "Madison", Customer = "Milwaukee", Demand = 10 },
        new { Brand = "Cart", Product = "D", Location = "Chicago", Customer = "Milwaukee", Demand = 15 },
        new { Brand = "Cart", Product = "C", Location = "Madison", Customer = "Milwaukee", Demand = 10 }
        }
group record by new { record.Location, record.Customer } into grouping
where (from o in grouping select o.Product).Distinct().Count() > 1
from duplicate in grouping
select duplicate
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample. This query just gets the grouped records by Location, Customer but it doesn't consider the Product's distint value. In the example above, the Product B & D have the same Location & Customer and hence they show up as Invalid. But, if I renamed Product D to be also B, then the query would show them as exception too. I am looking for the case where once we group by the location, customer I need to check the list of Unique Product and ensure the set is = 1. Hope, I didn't confuse you.

Comment: I think I follow. Better now?

Comment: Thanks. I am giving it a try now. Is there a way to have this query without the lambda expression? Just asking. If it's difficult, never mind