# Is there a easy way to filter out unique elements using linq?

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I have an xml document

```
<NumSet>
    <num>1</num>
    <num>2</num>
    <num>2</num>
    <num>3</num>
  </NumSet>
```

I want unique elements shown up, ie 1 and 3. not **distinct** which will also bring out 2.
How to do that? Do I have to use Group? Is there any concise way to do that?

Comment: SO users, if you're going to downvote, *PLEASE* explain why you have done it to the user, so that they may learn from their mistakes. Otherwise, they don't know what their mistake is. I personally don't know why this was voted down... it's short but perfectly understandable.

Comment: @Sheridan - I agree completely.   Whoever downvoted may have done so because there was no code shown (i.e., no shown attempt), but I wish SO would implement a system that forced downvoters to leave a comment, so at least folks can learn (if the reason is valid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you can use `GroupBy` and filter group which has only one item by using `Count() == 1`:

```
 var output =  XDocument.Load(xmlFile)
                        .Descendants("num")
                        .Select(e => e.Value)
                        .GroupBy(x => x)
                        .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
                        .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a `Distinct` `GroupBy` query... Take a look at the [Need help on Linq with group by and distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621648/need-help-on-linq-with-group-by-and-distinct) post here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
XElement xe = XElement.Parse(@"<NumSet><num>1</num><num>2</num><num>2</num><num>3</num></NumSet>");
var query = xe.Elements("num")
               .GroupBy(x => x.Value)
               .Where(x=>x.Count ()==1)
               .Select (x => x);
```

Answer (score 1):

To do what you need I'd say that yes, you need to use GrouBy, and then count the elements in each group, and return those that contains just one element. In code, this translates to:

```
var query = lst.GroupBy(x => x)
  .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)
  .Select(x => x.Key);
```

Comment: So the syntax is necessarily complicated. If I want to join the Query with another, should I use GroupJoin or Filter first then join?

Comment: I wouldn't say that is complicated :) think about what it does : it groups the elemnts, count how many there are in each groups, and returns the ones with only one results. For the second question ... it depends on the query you want to join, but probably it's for the best ask that in a new question.